# How dose a new consumer consume the messages produced in the past in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I am a user of Apache Kafka trying to run RabbitMQ.
Kafka supports a consumer to consume any messages that are produced before. (By re-widning 'offset' in Kafka's log)

I'd like to know whether RabbitMQ has the same functionality.
(A new consumer comes and requests all the messages after a certain point.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to know whether RabbitMQ has the same functionality

It does not.

Kafka is purpose-built for that feature - an event log that allows you to travel forward from a point.

RabbitMQ is a message queue - first in, first out. Once a message is handled, it is done and gone. There is no history or log to traverse.

---

There is a "recent history" plugin for RabbitMQ, but this does not provide the same feature set Kafka.

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-recent-history-exchange#readme

It only allows you to say something like "new consumers should get the last 20 messages, before continuing to get new messages".

Kafka, on the other hand, gives you a much more extensive history and the ability to start at the beginning and move forward as needed.

Comment: RabbitMQ consumer will receive the messages produced after its subscription, right? thanks

Comment: Assuming you have a single consumer on a queue, that consumer will receive any message in the queue, after the consumer connects and starts consuming. If there are 5 messages in the queue before the consumer connects, the consumer will receive those 5 messages and all messages that come in after

Comment: But once those 5 messages are gone, and another consumer connects to the same queue, the second consumer will not receive those 5 messages because the messages are already gone. there is no history, except with that plugin i mentioned

Comment: If the exchange semantic is 'Publish/Subscribe' or 'Topics', then all consumers will receive the same messages

Comment: @syko - not quite. if multiple consumers are connected to the same queue, only 1 of the consumers will receive a given message. if you need all consumers to receive the same message, each consumer needs its own queue. then you need to use an exchange type and routing key combination that sends a copy of the message to every queue that needs it.

Comment: pub/sub is typically accomplished with a "fanout" exchange type, where all bound queues will receive a copy of the message. while you're right about the pub/sub semantics saying all consumers should receive a copy of the message, the implementation is dependent on each consumer having it's own queue, not on the exchange type

Comment: I get your point. 'A queue per consumer' matters. thanks for your detailed comments. I appreciate it.